# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'intel_extension_for_pytorch'

Tags: pytorch, intel, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I am new to using pytorch on a gpu. I have been trying to use the intel_extension_for_pytorch on my windows 11 system with Intel Iris Xe graphics. I have installed the driver from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/785597/intel-arc-iris-xe-graphics-windows.html and oneAPI base toolkit for windows as was mentioned in the installation page.

However, I am getting ModuleNotFoundError while trying to import intel_extension_for_pytorch.

Can someone pls guide me.